# Increase timeout for fetch to avoid 504 gateway timeout

Tags: typescript, fetch-api, http-status-code-504

I got a typescript code which uses `fetch` to make a long running http request. The request can sometime take a while and I don't want a 504 gateway timeout to be thrown after the default timeout.

Is there a way to increase the time until a 504 error is thrown if no response is received for a `fetch` call?

Comment: @Fraction No. That question describes how to set a timeout for the request so it won't take too long. I want to do the exact opposite - increase the inner timeout of the request so it won't throw a 504 error after it waits for a reply which doesn't arrive and make it keep waiting

Comment: You can use polling, but I think WebSocket would be a better choice